# Can the App Pool user of a web application be given permissions to manage a list in central administration?

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, web-application

In Central Administration, I need to have a list that can be managed by the app pool user of another web application. I’ve tried everything from making this user a delegated administrator to given them full control, but they are still unable to CRUD this list. So, is there any known workaround to give a user who is not a farm administrator nor member of the central administration site permissions to just manage this list?

Answer (score 2):

To give a user who is not a farm administrator nor member of the central administration site permissions to just manage this list, you can just grant the user with permission on the list.

Navigate to the list->List Settings->Permission for this list->Stop Inheriting Permissions, grant the user with full control on the list.

Comment: Would this also work for creating the list?  As in, can I give them permission to create the list in Central Administration if it doesn't exist? I tried making the user a member of the central administration site, and that didn't work (unless there was something additional that I needed to do).